# OpenLDAP ldap_get_option() response

Tags: php, c, ldap, openldap

I'm working on OpenLDAP password policy implementation to app. I'm trying to get password is expiring, password expired notifications from OpenLDAP.

I set the current value

```
$ppolicy_control = array("oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1","iscritical" => true);
```

with `ldap_set_option()` for `LDAP_OPT_SERVER_CONTROLS` (password policy control)

I still don't get the password policy response from `ldap_get_option()`.

What I have learned, that OpenLDAP C API hasn't implemented `LDAP_OPT_SERVER_CONTROLS` case on ldap_get_option() method. Checking the packets on Wireshark shows the ppolicy response hooked to the packet.

Is there any workaround to pull the password policy response from OpenLDAP using PHP or OpenLDAP C API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ldap_control_find() API  and macro LDAP_CONTROL_PASSWORDPOLICYRESPONSE pass the same to ldap_parse_passwordpolicy_control() API to get the ppolicy response from the LDAP server

pseudo code

ctrl = ldap_control_find( LDAP_CONTROL_PASSWORDPOLICYRESPONSE)

call ldap_parse_passwordpolicy_control(ppolicyinfo.expire ,ppolicyinfograce)